# Hibernate Annoation for EnumMap<Enum,String> (OneToMany)

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, annotations, enum-map

I have troubles to find the correct hibernate annotation for a bean attribute. 
It´s an EnumMap variable. K is a EnumType and K a String. I saw many posts discussing similar topics but I didn´t saw any thread where they used a String as the map value. I guess this is maybe the problem here. I would like to map it as a OneToMany relation. Great would be if the key value of the EnumMap would be a string value in a table and the map should be nullable.
Is that possible? I tried this here:

```
@OneToMany
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EnumMap<IDType, String> ids;
```

and e.g. the enumerated annotation but nothing works. I get an exception:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: entities.persistent.IDContainer.ids
```

Would be very happy for any ideas. I am kind of lost...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a OneToMany, because it doesn't hold entities. So it's an ElementCollection. And you MUST use Map as the type, not EnumMap.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried this version already. But then another exception is thrown:       Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ids)]

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ElementCollection annotation:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<IDType, String> ids = new EnumMap<>(IDType.class);
```